# Conditional annotations in Django

Tags: django, annotate

I got simple requirement (not simple implementation), and figuring out how to achieve it without making multiple hits to db, and without `.extra()` in queryset.

```
Task:
  name = xxx
  status = models.IntegerField(choices=some_choices)
  project = ForeignKey(Project)

Project:
  name = xxx
  code = xxx
```

Projects contain Tasks which got various statuses. (Assume status=3 is Completed)
Now, I want to list out all projects with their total tasks and completed tasks, like below

1. Project 1, total_tasks=5, completed_tasks=2
2. Project 1, total_tasks=2, completed_tasks=1

I am able to get total_tasks with annotate, but not completed_tasks, since it required condition in annotation. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: How would You plan to do it with raw SQL anyway?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875122/django-and-conditional-aggregates

Comment: +1. So it is clear that, this kind of functionality is not there in core. But, is there any way we can achieve it using F() etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will help, but you can write your own custom annotation objects. I've just done it though without the conditional part. I based my solution on this link:
http://www.voteruniverse.com/Members/jlantz/blog/conditional-aggregates-in-django

but didn't use the example there. Instead I looked at the django code for aggregates and extended the Sum and Count objects themselves.

Comment: Not sure if the linked blog is just down for the moment or permanently, but here's an archived version in any case: http://web.archive.org/web/20101115170804/http://www.voteruniverse.com/Members/jlantz/blog/conditional-aggregates-in-django

Answer (score 10):

This feature is **new in Django 1.8.**

Refer to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

This is a possibility:

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
from django.db.models.expressions import F, Value, Case, When

projects = Project.objects.annotate(
        total_tasks=Count('task__pk'),
        completed_tasks=Count(Case(
           When(status=3, then=F('task__pk')),
           output_field=IntegerField()
        ))).all()
```

Comment: Beautiful! very well updated answer, thanks. should be in the `Count` docs themselves

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind additional queries, you can derive two querysets instead of one. The first can get you the total count and the second can filter on `tasks_status` and thereby get you the completed count.

```
from django.db.models import Count
all_projects = Project.objects.all()
total_counts = all_projects.annotate(count = Count('tasks'))
completed_counts = all_projects.filter(tasks_status = 3).annotate(count = Count('tasks'))
```

Comment: this is somewhat better than my brute approach, where I'm iterating all projects and attached queryset to get completed_counts.

But, it again forces us to match project vs completed_counts, may be in template or view

Comment: Agreed. You are obliged to match project against count in the template  or view.