# Django exclude from annotation count

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have following application:

```
from django.db import models


class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Job(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to annotate Workers query with count of completed jobs.

I'll try to do it with following script:

```
from myapp.models import Worker, Job
from django.db.models import Count

w = Worker.objects.create(name='Worker1')
Job.objects.create(worker=w, is_completed=False)
Job.objects.create(worker=w, is_completed=False)
Job.objects.create(worker=w, is_completed=True)
Job.objects.create(worker=w, is_completed=True)

workers = Worker.objects.all().annotate(num_jobs=Count('job'))
workers[0].num_jobs    
# >>> 4
workers = Worker.objects.all().exclude(job__is_completed=False).annotate(num_jobs=Count('job'))
# >>> []
```

Result of the last query is empty. How to exclude elements from reverse relation?

Django 1.8, python 2.7

**UPD.** I would like to have all workers in queryset, even those, who has a zero jobs

Comment: [this SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875122/django-and-conditional-aggregates) is worth reading. apparently it's not that simple to annotate all records and count based on a condition

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**update**: ok I played a bit with this to generate the solution and I think I got it using [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

> Conditional expressions let you use if ... elif ... else logic within
>   filters, annotations, aggregations, and updates. A conditional
>   expression evaluates a series of conditions for each row of a table
>   and returns the matching result expression.

Note: **[Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)** (such as `Case` and `When`) are **new in Django 1.8**, as pointed out by @Pynchia

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Sum, Case, When

workers = Worker.objects.annotate(
              num_jobs=Sum(
                  Case(
                      When(job__is_completed=True, then=1),
                      default=0,  
                      output_field=IntegerField()
                  )
               )
           )
```

now, each worker will have a num_jobs which will be an Integer that shows how many completed jobs that worker has :)

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it does not work. It seems to count all jobs completed or not, and it does not annotate all the workers. Please provide an explanation of what it does with an example

Comment: @Pynchia for me it works. You must have done something wrong.

Comment: does it annotate workers with a completed job count of zero?

Comment: @Pynchia you were right. I updated the answer to annotate workers with a completed job count

Comment: Wow, brilliant! I cannot play with it right now, but it looks like a great step forward. I think you should mention `Case` and `When` conditional expressions are new, having been introduced with Django 1.8

Comment: One more thing: are you sure you need the `Q` operator? Maybe you can get rid of it and use `When(job__is_completed=True, then=1),...` only, according to the examples in the docs

Comment: @Pynchia yeah works without Q objects as well, just tested it. updated the answer

Comment: Great! Fixed my day. was pulling my hair from yesterday on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is 2 options here. First one is straight `Q` filter on `Count`:

```py
from myapp.models import Worker
from django.db.models import Count, Q

workers = Worker.objects.annotate(
    completed_jobs_count=Count("job", filter=Q(job__is_completed=True))
)
```

And the second is excluding `Q` filter on `Count` (sometimes it's needed because `Count` doesn't has straight `exclude` option):

```py
from myapp.models import Worker
from django.db.models import Count, Q

workers = Worker.objects.annotate(
    completed_jobs_count=Count("job", filter=~Q(job__is_completed=False))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following

```
workers = Worker.objects.filter(job__is_completed=True)).annotate(num_jobs=Count('job__is_completed'))
```

annotates those workers who have at least one job completed.
Those whth a count of zero job completed are not included in the result queryset.

In case you want ALL workers to appear in the result queryset, it would be great if we could write

```
workers = Worker.objects.annotate(num_jobs=CountIf('job__is_completed', job__is_completed=True))
```

but unfortunately, we cannot.
So I am out of my depth here and I believe my answer is partial.
I welcome the intervention of somebody more competent then I am who could shed some light on the matter.

For reference, see this [Django proposed feature](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11305) (closed)

and [this SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875122/django-and-conditional-aggregates)

**UPDATE:** Django 1.8 introduced conditional expressions. @BogdiG's answer uses such new operators to solve the problem. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

*Update*

If you want a count of completed job for every worker, than we could use subquery through `.extra()`:

```
Worker.objects.extra(select={'jobs_done': 
     'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {job_tbl} WHERE worker_id = {worker_tbl}.id AND is_completed'
     .format(worker_tbl=Worker._meta.db_table, job_tbl=Job._meta.db_table)})
```

It's great that Django now supports the Python mapping of conditional expression `SUM(CASE WHEN is_completed = True THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` in syntax described in [@BogdiG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31853259/165603).

---

Removed things about `filter/exclude`

Comment: I have removed my answer because it would not return all the workers, but only those with at least one completed job. I believe your solution suffers from the same problem. I believe the OP wants to annotate ALL workers with the number of completed jobs, even if it's zero.

Comment: @Pynchia I see, then It's not a filter thing, updating my answer.

Comment: I haver re-posted my answer, but I am not sure it satisfies the question. It would be great if the OP clarified if he/she wants ALL workers in the result queryset