# Annotating results of complicated subqueries in Django 1.8 to QuerySet

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have to following DB schema:

```
main_account
- username

invoice
- amount
- currency: 'EUR' or 'USD' or 'GBP'
- username (main_account has many invoices)
```

and my goal is to list the "top payers" in dollars. Thus, I have to calculate a "total_paid" sum for each user from the invoice table (and take currency conversions into account). I also wish to filter by this "total_paid".

My current SQL looks like:

```
SELECT main_account.username, total_paid
FROM main_account JOIN
(
    SELECT username,
        (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM invoice WHERE main_account.username = invoice.username AND invoice.currency = 'EUR') AS total_eur,
        (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM invoice WHERE main_account.username = invoice.username AND invoice.currency = 'USD') AS total_usd,
        (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM invoice WHERE main_account.username = invoice.username AND invoice.currency = 'GBP') AS total_gbp,
        (SELECT (IFNULL(total_usd,0) + 1.12 * IFNULL(total_eur,0) + 1.41 * IFNULL(total_gbp,0))) AS total_paid
    FROM main_account
) as tbl
ON main_account.username = tbl.username
WHERE total_paid >= 2000
ORDER BY total_paid
```

I'd like to know how to accomplish this with Django's ORM.

It seems that the solution is something along the lines of:

```
MainAccount.objects
    .annotate(total_paid=???)
    .filter(total_paid__gte=2000)
    .order_by('total_paid')
```

Some notes:

- MainAccount.extra(...).filter(...).order_by(...) will not work. Values created in extra can not be filtered over.
- I've tried MainAccount.annotate(total_paid=RawSQL(...)) which worked fine but bumped into a weird bug when adding the .filter(). For some reason, the filter call mutates the RawSQL object with a SQL parameter and then a `"not all arguments converted during string formatting"` error is thrown.

Comment: Have a look here which was answered earlier today : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852672/django-exclude-from-annotation-count/31853259#31853259 ; try using Conditional Expressions,  new in Django 1.8 ; let me know if you can figure it out after reading the answer/docs

Comment: I'll try that. However, I already tried creating the SQL above with MySQL's CASE and it was terribly slow (~30s for query) against the current version (less than second).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As kindly pointed out by BogdiG, Django 1.8 Conditional Expressions are the solution.

Python/Django:

```
MainAccount.objects.annotate(
    total_paid = Sum(
        Case(
            When(invoices__currency='EUR', then=F('invoices__amount') * 1.12),
            When(invoices__currency='USD', then=F('invoices__amount')),
            When(invoices__currency='GBP', then=F('invoices__amount') * 1.41)
        )
    )
).filter(total_paid__gte=2000).order_by('total_paid')
```

which generates SQL similar to:

```
SELECT  main_account.username, 
        SUM(
            CASE 
                WHEN invoice.currency = 'EUR' THEN (invoice.amount * 1.12) 
                WHEN invoice.currency = 'USD' THEN invoice.amount 
                WHEN invoice.currency = 'GBP' THEN (invoice.amount * 1.41) 
                ELSE NULL 
            END
        ) AS total_paid 
FROM main_account 
    INNER JOIN invoice ON ( main_account.username = invoice.username ) 
GROUP BY main_account.username 
HAVING total_paid >= '2000' 
ORDER BY total_paid;
```

Comment: This feature is amazing. Certainly incentive for me to upgrade to 1.8